# What am I doing wrong with .splice()

Tags: javascript, if-statement, splice

I'm just trying to get comfortable with .slice(), and .splice().  Why doesn't this code work?  According to w3Schools .splice() takes 3 arguments, (index at which to begin adding/removing elements, # of elements to be removed, and what to add). Why does this function not work? P.S. Ignore they y, its just there as part of my experimenting.

```
let x = "Hello I like milk";
let y = ''

if(x[0] !== '(') {
 x = x.split(' ').splice(0, 0, '(');


}






console.log(x)
```

Comment: `splice` returns the removed elements, not the array it was called on. Call splice with 0, and an array of 0 elements will be returned

Comment: If I use splice, shouldn't the original array be changed?

Comment: Yes, but you *reassigned* `x`

Comment: If i assign it to y, it still doesnt work though, even if y is set to an empty array, or if I use join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[splice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) returns a removed items. Well the original array is changed, but you replaced it with the return value of splice(), resulting no elements. If you mean to add element at the beginning of the array, it should be like this

```
let x = "Hello I like milk";
let y = ''

if(x[0] !== '(') {
    x = x.split(' ');
    x.splice(0, 0, '(');
}

console.log(x)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.  So I always would have to do this in  2 steps?

Comment: yes, but if you really want the shorter way, you can use `x.unshift("(");`

Comment: Right, I just want to stop being scared of splice hahaha.